# Problems obtaining GPS location after mock location

Tags: android, android-location

I am using Android 5.1.1 on lenovo p70-A.
I was using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.incorporateapps.fakegps.fre to mock my location with GPS in device only mode. The problem is there that now I can't obtain my real location in device only mode no matter if mock location is enabled or disabled. Any ideas how can I fix it?

P.s I have enabled xposed module called "mock mock location" which tell selected apps that mock location is off. I have set it for only one app.

Comment: If their app isn't properly clearing the mock location providers, you may need to restart your phone after you disable "Allow Mock Locations" in the developer settings.

Comment: I have faced the issue sometimes. I usually use 'GPS status and toolbox' app from play store to reset GPS data (cold start) and download fresh A-GPS data and then restart the device. The above method works for any mock location app. But this time I have used some xposed module called [fakelocation](https://github.com/j2rong/FakeLocation). It doesn't need to allow mock location but allows per app fake location setting. After I disabled and uninstalled the module, I am still unable to get the original location in that specific app where I applied fake location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can open settings in the search bar write "fused location" clear the data and force stop and congratulations :) you don't have to restart the phone .